# What are the <frozen importlib._bootstrap> lines from trace?

Tags: python, import, trace

Suppose we have the following script `tracetest.py`:

```py
import simpy

def clock(env, name, tick):
    while True:
        print(name, env.now)
        yield env.timeout(tick)

env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(clock(env, 'fast', 0.5))
env.process(clock(env, 'slow', 1))

env.run(until=2)
```

And we run this command:

```bash
$ python -m trace -t tracetest.py > foo.txt
```

And then run:

```bash
$ head foo.txt
```

I see the following:

```bash
 --- modulename: tracetest, funcname: <module>
tracetest.py(1): import simpy
 --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _find_and_load
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1024):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __init__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(166): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(167):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __enter__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(170):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _get_module_lock
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(185): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(186): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(187): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(188): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(189): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(190): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(192): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(193): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(196):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __init__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(72): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(73): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(74): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(75): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(76): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(77): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(198): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(209): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(211): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(213): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(171):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: acquire
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(106): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(107): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(108): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(109): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(110): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(111): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(112): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(113): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(114): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(110): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(123): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1025): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1026): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _find_and_load_unlocked
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(988): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(989): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(990): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1002):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _find_spec
```

What are these `<frozen importlib._bootstrap>` lines about?